# Move label to RIGHT of checkbox in Webforms

Tags: webforms

When setting the label to "inline", Webforms will place the label to the left of my checkbox. Is there any way I can move it to the right?

Here's what it looks like right now, I want the label to be to the RIGHT of the box.

[image: This is what I have right now, I'd like to move the label to the right.]

thanks

Comment: This is CSS related question, can you please give us some URL to look at your webform?

Comment: it's hosted locally right now. I'm using bootstrap if that helps

Comment: Tell me which version of Webform you are using?

Comment: version 7.x-3.20

Comment: I just checked out and by default label doesn't show as you wrote but it show the way you want to be. By the way, by setting the label to show 'inline' you don't affect the checkbox label but component label.

I assume that the checkbox label shows in the way that you described because of other CSS (maybe from Bootstrap). You need to give me some URL where I can see your webform so I could give you concrete answer...

Comment: Was able to get what I wanted by using a markup instead and just hiding the label. What's the difference between the checkbox label and component label?

Comment: When you adding the field you write in the title of that field, that is the component label. When you are adding the options in that field in format 'key|Readable name', the 'Readable name' from format is the label for that checkbox that stands beside square in frontend...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drupal is spitting out the markup as `[title][field]` and what you want is `[field][title]` so to accomplish this you need to override Drupal's default theme implementation of your field. To do this copy example.com/modules/field/theme/field.tpl.php to your theme template folder(if one does not already exist in there ...sites/all/themes/my_theme/templates) and modify the template file to your desired markup.
When naming your template file you can restrict it to the webform fields, Drupal will use the most specific template it finds in the following order:

- field--field-name--content-type.tpl.php
- field--content-type.tpl.php
- field--field-name.tpl.php
- field--field-type.tpl.php
- field.tpl.php (in your theme)
- field.tpl.php (in drupal's field module)

Take a look at this link, [Drupal documentation on field.tpl.php](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!theme!field.tpl.php/7)

Hope this helps.

Comment: I moved things around, and saved field.tpl.php in sites/all/themes/my_theme/templates and don't see any changes

Comment: did you flush cache before previewing changes?

Answer (score 0):

Another option, which I found useful, is to check the css of the form label.  My checkboxes were indeed on the left, but looking at the label.option, i saw that the float was to the left.

I changed this to float:none, and it seems to have fixed my input box.

label.option {
    display: inline;
    font-weight: normal;
    float: none;
}